# Why do I get an error when I put a letter into a string?

Tags: string, vba, error-handling, double, type-conversion

I am making a small program that checks the number you type in up to 4 and each number says something different. But I want it to say "Pick a number instead." when someone puts in a letter instead. Basically my else is supposed to be only if the answer contains a letter, but when I run the program, and type a letter then press enter, I get an error about not being able to convert the answer to a double, and I've looked everywhere to solve this problem but nothing comes close. Please help, I would much appreciate it. I typed a, pressed enter, and this is the error I get (although it's with all letters. Not just a.) The error is: {"Conversion from string ""a"" to type 'Double' is not valid."}
The error occurs when the If statement begins.

```
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then

        Dim Answer As String

        Answer = txtAnswer.Text

        If Answer = 1 Then
            txtResponse.Text = "Good"
        ElseIf Answer = 2 Then
            txtResponse.Text = "Good again"
        ElseIf Answer = 3 Then
            txtResponse.Text = "Not too good"
        ElseIf Answer = 4 Then
            txtResponse.Text = "Terrible"
        ElseIf Answer > 4 Or Answer < 1 Then
            txtResponse.Text = "Wrong Answer"
        Else
            txtResponse.Text = "pick a number"
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: 1 is a number, "1" is String. So either you change `Dim Answer As Integer` and `Answer = CInt(txtAnswer.Text)`, or change all the IF block to "1", "2", etc. But you cannot use ">", "<" for String.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you are looking for.

```
Sub PickANumber()
Dim Valid As Boolean
Dim Data, Answer As String

While Valid = False
    Data = InputBox("Enter number between 1 and 4")
    If IsNumeric(Data) And Data >= 1 And Data <= 4 Then
            Valid = True
        Else
            Valid = False
            Data = MsgBox("Please input a valid number.", vbRetryCancel)
            If Data = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    End If
Wend

    Select Case Data
    Case 1
        Answer = "Good"
    Case 2
        Answer = "Good again"
    Case 3
        Answer = "Not too good"
    Case 4
        Answer = "Terrible"
    End Select
    MsgBox Answer

End Sub
```

Comment: Everything in the line of code works, except for inputting a letter again. I still get the error message:  {"Conversion from string ""a"" to type 'Double' is not valid."} the error appears at the line of code: If IsNumeric(Data) And Data >= 1 And Data <= 4 Then

Comment: Please post your whole code? I do not get that error when inputting a letter more than once.

Comment: That is the entire code, except for the class, end class, and key down event on the text box. And it's when I insert 1 letter and press enter, it says it wont convert single to double, but i dont have anything declared as a single nor a double.